# merge two json arrays with push on item value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following json array:

array 1:

```
fruits1 = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","color":"yellow"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","color":"red"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","color":"green"}]
```

array 2:

```
fruits2 = [{"fruit":"banana","sold":"1","stock":"3"},{"fruit":"apple","sold":"3","stock":"5"},{"fruit":"kiwi","sold":"2","stock":"3"}]
```

I would like to get just one array which has the results merged according to the fruits value like this:

```
fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","color":"yellow","sold":"1","stock":"3"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","color":"red","sold":"3","stock":"5"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","color":"green","sold":"2","stock":"3"}]
```

I need to do something like

```
    foreach item.fruit where fruit = fruit from initial array 
    fruits.push item
```

Any idea?

Comment: [Maybe this link could be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164060/combine-merge-objects-in-array-based-upon-common-value)

Comment: thank you. I am not looking to group however. Let me update the question

Comment: I was thinking about the [$.extend] (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), but if I'm not wrong it merge based on the name of the object key, in this case you should swap the key with the value and merge and then swap again, but I don't think it is very optimized. Another solution is a nasted interation, but still not so good, let's wait someone more capable than me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
 function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
   var obj3 = {};
   for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
   for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
   return obj3;
 }


 var obj1 = [];
 for (var i = 0; i <  fruits1.length ; i++) { 
     obj1[fruits1[i].fruit] = fruits1[i]; 
 }

 var obj2 = []; 
 for (var i = 0; i <  fruits2.length ; i++) { 
     obj2[fruits2[i].fruit] = fruits2[i]; 
 }

 var fruits = []
 for (var key in obj1) { 
   fruits.push(merge_options(obj1[key],obj2[key]));
 }

  console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: in the end this was the working/better solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with javascript

```
// create a hash like {fruit_name -> object}
f1 = {};
fruits1.forEach(function(p) {
  f1[p.fruit] = p;
});

// merge second array into above hash on fruit_name
fruits2.forEach(function(p) {
  for (var a in p) { f1[p.fruit][a] = p[a];}
});

//fruits1 will now contain result; 
//if you don't want to spoil fruit1 array, clone p inside 'fruits1.forEach' above before assigning it to 'f1[p.fruit]'. And at the end, create a new array out of f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic way that works with your data:

```
function joinObjects(initial, other, predicate, valueSelector) {
    if(typeof(predicate) !== 'function') throw 'predicate must be a function';
    if(typeof(valueSelector) !== 'function') throw 'valueSelector must be a function';

    // make a clone of the original object so its not modified
    var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, initial);

    // iterate over the initial and other collections
    for(var cloneKey in clone) {
        if (!clone.hasOwnProperty(cloneKey)) continue;
        for(var otherKey in other) {
            if (!other.hasOwnProperty(otherKey)) continue;

            // if the predicate is truthy, get the values
            if (predicate(clone[cloneKey], other[otherKey])) {

                // pull only the values you want to merge
                var values = valueSelector(other[otherKey]);

                // iterate over the values add them to the cloned initial object
                for(var valueKey in values) {
                    if (values.hasOwnProperty(valueKey)) {
                        clone[cloneKey][valueKey] = values[valueKey];
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return clone;
}

var fruits1 = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","color":"yellow"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","color":"red"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","color":"green"}];
var fruits2 = [{"fruit":"banana","sold":"1","stock":"3"},{"fruit":"apple","sold":"3","stock":"5"},{"fruit":"kiwi","sold":"2","stock":"3"}];
var finalFruits = joinObjects(fruits1, fruits2,
    function(left, right) { return left.fruit == right.fruit },
    function(other) { 
        return { 
            sold: other.sold,
            stock: other.stock
        };
    });

console.log(finalFruits);
```